# How to fix error in python: Name error: name is not defined

Tags: python

When I type the below code and run the program for getting the text in the entry by using `hostEntry2.get()` then it will show

> NameError: name `hostEntry2` is not defined.

I have tried to remove the `for` loop (then it works), but with the below code it won't work.
I expect the text entered in the entry box should be displayed.

```
from tkinter import *
host1 = ""
database1 = ""
user1 = ""

def db():
    window1 = Tk()
    window1.title("GIVE INFORAMATION ABOUT DATABASE")

    F0 = Frame(window1, relief = SUNKEN)
    F0.pack(side = LEFT)

    l1 = ["host", "database", "user"]
    l2 = ["HOST", "DATABASE", "USER"]

    for i in range(len(l1)):
        exec("%s2 = Label(F0, font = ('OpenSansCondensed', 12), text = \"  ENTER THE %s:\", width = 30, anchor = \"w\")"%(l1[i], l2[i]))
        exec("%s2.grid(row = %s, column = 0)"%(l1[i], i))
        exec("%sEntry2 = Entry(F0, font = ('OpenSansCondensed', 12), textvariable = \"\", insertwidth = 4, justify = 'right')"%(l1[i]))
        exec("%sEntry2.grid(row = %s, column = 1)"%(l1[i],i))

    submitBtn = Button(F0, padx = 16, pady = 5, font = ('OpenSansCondensed', 10), width = 8, text = " OK ", command = lambda: [f for f in [submit_for_db(hostEntry2.get(), databaseEntry2.get(), userEntry2.get()), window1.destroy()]])
    submitBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    window1.mainloop()

def submit_for_db(host_enterred, database_enterred, user_enterred, password_enterred):
    global host1
    global database1
    global user1
    global password1
    host1 = host_enterred
    database1 = database_enterred
    user1 = user_enterred
    password1 = password_enterred

db()
```

Comment: Please don't do this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you have said

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question is not clear. You refer to `hostEntry2.get()` but there is no usage of `hostEntry` or `get()` in your code. Also, you do not show how your buttons are defined so we cannot run your code. Please show us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run and shows your problem.

Comment: can you add the part where you actually use 'hostEntry2.get()'

Comment: The first comment means that you are using the `exec` function for no good reason. That makes your code hard to understand. The `exec` function is also dangerous and should be used only when necessary, which does not seem to be the case here. (A user could take over your system, erase files, and do other nasty things by means of `exec`.) Apart from your other issues, you should re-work  your code and remove the `exec`s. You also use the old-fashioned `%` way to format strings but that is deprecated. You should use the `format` method or f-strings.

Comment: I am using the hostEntry2.get() int this button command:           submitBtn = Button(F0, padx = 16, pady = 5, font = ('OpenSansCondensed', 10), width = 8, text = " OK ", command = lambda: [f for f in [submit_for_db(hostEntry2.get(), databaseEntry2.get(), userEntry2.get()), window1.destroy()]])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use `exec` here.

```
l2 = ["HOST", "DATABASE", "USER"]

for i, label in enumerate(l2):
    item = Label(F0, font=('OpenSansCondensed', 12), text="  ENTER THE %s:".format(label), width=30, anchor ="w")
    item.grid(row=i, column=0)
    entry = Entry(F0, font=('OpenSansCondensed', 12), textvariable="", insertwidth=4, justify='right')
    entry.grid(row=i, column = 1)
    entries.append(entry)

submitBtn = Button(F0, padx = 16, pady = 5, font = ('OpenSansCondensed', 10), width = 8, text = " OK ", command = lambda: [f for f in [submit_for_db([entry.get() for entry in entries]), window1.destroy()]])
submitBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
```

(Note, I can't see where you are using the Labels, though.)

Comment: How is it shorter than mine?

Comment: That part hasn't changed. The text is sent to `submit_for_db`, just like in your original version.

Answer (score 0):

Function `submit_for_db` is not defined, i **don't recommend** to use `exec()` functions

[image]

Comment: I have added the submit_for_db now. As I am new to coding can please suggest me why not to use the exec() function. I used it to make the code shorter.